# Angular 2 template parse error Missing expected )

Tags: angular

I am getting the following exception:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 19 in [(model.DaysOfWeek & 0x20) !== 0] in PriceComponent@129:65 ("ox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="DaysOfWeek" [ERROR ->][checked]="(model.DaysOfWeek & 0x20) !== 0" (change)="model.DaysOfWeek ^= 0x20" /> Monday
          "): PriceComponent@129:65
```

on this binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="DaysOfWeek" [checked]="(model.DaysOfWeek & 0x20) !== 0" (change)="model.DaysOfWeek ^= 0x20" /> Monday
```

The binding expressions look valid to me, so I am puzzled as to why it fails? DaysOfWeek is a property of type number that is bit encoded with day of week flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in [Template expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions) and [Template statements](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-statements) it's not allow the bitwise operators | and &:

**Template expressions**

> no support for the bitwise operators | and &

**Template statements**

> However, certain JavaScript syntax is not allowed:
>
> - new
> - increment and decrement operators, ++ and -- operator assignment,    such as += and -=
> - the bitwise operators | and &
> - the template expression operators

Comment: maybe, you could extract to a method in js/ts file.